# laravel 5.1 foreach Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreach

i am having 3-4 for each in my code which all use Eloquent and in all of them i get the same error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

when i dd the first argument of  foreach which is an eloquent it returns an array of json with all the data in database of that table so its not returning null though i know it may break or bring null while in a foreach loop but i dont know where   place one of them with model and controller here so here is the loop it self

```
                                <?php foreach(\App\Menu::all()->where('slug','main')->first()->items as $top_menu): ?>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="<?php echo e(URL($top_menu->link)); ?>" <?php if($top_menu->link_blank): ?> target="_blank" <?php endif; ?>>
                                        <?php echo e($top_menu->title); ?>

                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and here is my controller

```
class MenuItemsController extends AdminController
```

{

```
var $object = 'menu_items';
var $route_name = 'menu_items';
var $object_title = 'item';
var $object_titles = 'items';

var $attachments_config = [
    'main_image' => [],
    'default_thumb_sizes' => [],
    'require' => ['main_image']
];

var $dt_fields_db = [];
var $dt_fields_heading = ['شناسه','منو','عنوان','موقعیت','نمایش','ثبت','عملیات'];
var $dt_fields_full = [
    'id' => ['menu_items.id'],
    'menu_title' => ['menus.title'],
    'title' => ['menu_items.title'],
    'position' => ['menu_items.position'],
    'display' => ['menu_items.display'],
    'created_at' => ['menu_items.created_at'],
    'actions' => ['actions']
];

var $messages = array();

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    view()->share(['attachments_config' => $this->attachments_config]);
}

function index() {

    $data['extra_assets'] = array(
        array('type' => 'css','path' => 'datatables/datatables.bootstrap.css'),
        array('type' => 'js','path' => 'datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js'),
        array('type' => 'js','path' => 'datatables/datatables.bootstrap.js'),
        array('type' => 'script','path' => 'pagescripts/shared/datatables_script.php'),
    );

    $data['dt_fields_heading'] = $this->dt_fields_heading;
    $data['dt_fields'] = $this->dt_fields_full;

    $data['heading'] = $this->object_titles;
    return view('admin.shared.datatable',$data);
}

function datatable() {
    $this->dt_filtered_actions = dt_actions_filter($this->route_name,['edit','delete']);

    $objects = DB::table('menu_items')
        ->join('menus', 'menu_items.menu_id','=', 'menus.id')
        ->select([
            'menu_items.id',
            'menus.title as menu_title',
            'menu_items.title',
            'menu_items.display',
            'menu_items.position',
            'menu_items.created_at'
        ]);

    return Datatables::of($objects)
        ->editColumn('display', function($model) {return label_status($model->display);})
        ->editColumn('created_at', function($model) {return ($date = jDate::forge($model->created_at)->format('%H:%M:%S - %y/%m/%d'))?$date:"";})
        ->addColumn('actions', function($model) {
            return dt_actions($this->route,$model->id,$this->dt_filtered_actions);
        })
        ->make(true);
}

function add() {

    $data['extra_assets'] = array(
        array('type' => 'js','path' => 'select2/select2.full.min.js'),
        array('type' => 'css','path' => 'select2/select2.min.css'),
        array('type' => 'css','path' => 'select2/select2-bootstrap.css'),
        array('type' => 'helper','name' => 'select2'),
    );

    $data['menus'] = Menu::all()->lists('title','id');

    $data['heading'] = 'add'.$this->object_title;
    return view('admin.'.$this->route_name.'.add',$data);
}

function create(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'menu_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $input = $request->all();

    $input['display'] = (isset($input['display']))?$input['display']:0;

    $menu = Menu::find($input['menu_id']);
    if($menu->items->count() == $menu->capacity) {
        $this->messages[] = array('type' => 'danger', 'text' => 'menu is full');
        Session::flash('messages', $this->messages);
        return back();
    }

    MenuItem::create($input);

    $this->messages[] = array('type' => 'success', 'text' => 'success.');
    Session::flash('messages', $this->messages);
    return redirect()->route('admin.'.$this->route_name.'.index');
}

function edit(MenuItem $MenuItem) {
    $data['object'] = $MenuItem;

    $data['extra_assets'] = array(
        array('type' => 'script','path' => 'pagescripts/shared/image_preview_script.php'),

        array('type' => 'js','path' => 'select2/select2.full.min.js'),
        array('type' => 'css','path' => 'select2/select2.min.css'),
        array('type' => 'css','path' => 'select2/select2-bootstrap.css'),
        array('type' => 'helper','name' => 'select2'),

        array('type' => 'js','path' => 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js'),
        array('type' => 'js','path' => 'ckeditor/config.js'),
        array('type' => 'js','path' => 'ckfinder/ckfinder.js'),
        array('type' => 'js','path' => 'ckfinder/config.js'),
        array('type' => 'script','path' => 'pagescripts/shared/ckeditor_script.php'),
    );

    $data['menus'] = Menu::all()->lists('title','id');

    $data['heading'] = 'edit'.$this->object_title;
    return view('admin.'.$this->route_name.'.edit',$data);
}

function update(MenuItem $MenuItem,\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'menu_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $input = $request->all();

    $input['display'] = (isset($input['display']))?$input['display']:0;

    $MenuItem->update($input);

    $this->messages[] = array('type' => 'success', 'text' => 'success.');
    Session::flash('messages', $this->messages);
    return redirect()->back();
}

function delete(\Illuminate\Http\Request $requests,MenuItem $MenuItem) {
    if($requests->ajax() && $MenuItem->delete()) {
        return "OK";
    } else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}

function deleteall(\Illuminate\Http\Request $requests) {
    $ids = $requests->get('ids');
    if($requests->ajax()) {
        foreach (explode(',',$ids) as $id) {
            if(intval($id)) MenuItem::find($id)->delete();
        }
        return "OK";
    } else {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please narrow your code to the lines where error happens, there's no need to post all the code for controller.

Comment: By the way if you do `\App\Menu::all()->where('slug','main')->first()->items` you will load all menu items in memory, filter the collection you get and then get the items from the first one. You should instead  switch to `\App\Menu::where('slug','main')->first()->items()->get()` (you can eager load the items as well but in this case there's no benefit)

Comment: @u_mulder sorry for that i didnt know that which part of controller i am doing wrong

Comment: @apokryfos thank you but can it be the part that causes that non object error can it solve that ?

Comment: no it won't solve that but it's just good practice. Your error is probably to do with no menu item having a slug=main

Comment: @apokryfos Right to the point  thanks you man that solved my problem You saved my day :) i owe you one thanks Thumbs Up

Answer (score 1):

the problem was because my database table didn't got any row by the slug of menu and the query returned null and that error happens that error generally happens when your query returns null thanks all for help